# Problemas desconocidos con react 

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema que realmente me tiene muy confundido, por no saber donde se encuentra el problema.

tengo un componente principal que pasa propiedades a otros subcomponentes de manera interna.

```
 <Evaluations
     dataA={a.data}
     dataB={b.data}
     dataC={c.data}
/>
```

Dentro de mi componente evaluations tengo lo siguiente:

```
<ComponentA data={props.dataA} />
<ComponentB data={props.dataB} />
<ComponentC data={props.dataC} />
```

El componente A y el componente C reciben correctamente las propiedades, pero el componente B en particular al hacer un `console.log(props.data)` me muestra el objecto correctamente.

```
data: {
 id: 1,
 category: 1,
 name: 'Hola mundo'
}
```

sin embargo si hago un `console.log(props.data.category)` me dice que es `undefined` por consecuencia tampoco puedo renderizar el texto de la propiedad, porque existe, pero al intentar acceder directamente a el NO.

Otro dato interesante, solo me deja acceder a la propiedad `name`, las demás no existe

¿Alguien sabe que pasa?

Comment: ¿De que tipo es `props.data`?, me parece que tiene que ver con el optional chaining operation, es decir hay unbalanced dataset.